# I need help accessing the containerImg in my deployment.yaml as vscode marks it as an value not defined error

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Files in question are below; the line in spec -> containers -> image is marked as in error for some reason.

deployment.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.deployment.app_name}}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.specs.replicaCount}}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ .Values.deployment.app_name}}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ .Values.deployment.app_name}}
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: {{ .Values.deployment.app_name}}
        image: {{ .Values.deployment.containerImg}} (error here in vscode)
        ports:
        - containerPort: {{.Values.deployment.containerPort}}
```

values.yaml

```yaml
replicaCount: 4

deployment:
  app_name: "my-nginx-app"
  containerPort: 80
  containerImg: "nginx:1.25.0-alpine"
```

Comment: What is the actual error?  At a glance, the file seems fine to me.  (The container `name:` is local to its Pod and doesn't need to be configurable; similarly, the `containerPort:` is normally a property of the image and doesn't need to be configured either.  Consider including `.Release.Name` somewhere in the Deployment `name:` as a standard pattern.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using [Helm lint](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_lint/)?

Might provide additional information about the error.

Comment: RanAbitbul it just says value is not defined but no I have not tried Helm Lint, I am new to Helm

Comment: @RendezYT No problem, you should have `helm lint` command available since you have helm installed, try running this command in your helm directory:
`helm lint . -f values.yaml`